# Change the labels of a colorbar from increasing to decreasing values

Tags: matplotlib, max, label, minimum, colorbar

I'd like to change the labels for the colorbar from increasing to decreasing values. When I try to do this via `vmin` and `vmax` I get the error message:

> minvalue must be less than or equal to maxvalue

So, for example I'd like the colorbar to start at 20 on the left and go up to 15 on the right.

This is my code for the colorbar so far, but in this example the values go from 15 to 20 and I'd like to reverse that order:

```
cmap1 = mpl.cm.YlOrBr_r

norm1 = mpl.colors.Normalize(15,20)

cb1   = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(colorbar1, cmap=cmap1, norm=norm1, orientation='horizontal')

cb1.set_label('magnitude')
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The colorbars displayed below are probably not *exactly* like yours, as they are just *example* colorbars to function as a proof of concept.

In the following I assume you have a colorbar similar to this, with increasing values to the right:

[image: Original colorbar]

## Method 1: Inverting the x-axis

#### Inverts the whole x-axis of the colorbar

If you want to *invert* the x-axis, meaning that the values on the x-axis are descending to the right, making the colorbar "mirrored", you can make use of the [`ColorbarBase`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase)'s `ax` attribute:

```
cb1   = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(colorbar1,
                                  cmap=cmap1,
                                  norm=norm1,
                                  orientation='horizontal')
cb1.ax.invert_xaxis()
```

This gives.the output below.

[image: Colorbar with inverted x-axis]

It is also possible to change the number of ticklabels by setting the colorbars `locator`. Here the [`MultipleLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) is used, although you can use many [other locators](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-locating) as well.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

cb1.locator = MultipleLocator(1) # Show ticks only for each multiple of 1
cb1.update_ticks()
cb1.ax.invert_xaxis()
```

[image: Colorbar with inverted x-axis and MultipleLocator]

## Method 2: Using custom ticklabels

#### Reverses the order of the ticklabels, keeping the orientation of the colorbar

If you want the orientation of the colorbar itself as it is, and only reverse the order in which the ticklabels appear, you can use the `set_ticks` and `set_ticklabels` methods. This is more of a "brute force" approach than the previous solution.

```
cb1.set_ticks(np.arange(15, 21))
cb1.set_ticklabels(np.arange(20, 14, -1))
```

This gives the colorbar seen below. Note that the colors are kept intact, only the tick locations and ticklabels have changed.

[image: Colorbar with custom ticklabels]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution for producing the colorbar in Method 2:

```
cmap1 = cmap1.reversed()
cb1.ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me: variable_you_want.ax.invert_yaxis()