# Reverse color order of colorbar (not colormap) (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe of 350 rows × 16 columns of just 0 and 1.

I create a correlation matrix

```
dummy.corr(method ='kendall')
```

I'm plotting a correlogram:

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(19, 15))
plt.matshow(dummy.corr(), fignum=f.number)
plt.xticks(range(dummy.select_dtypes(['number']).shape[1]), dummy.select_dtypes(['number']).columns, fontsize=14, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(range(dummy.select_dtypes(['number']).shape[1]), dummy.select_dtypes(['number']).columns, fontsize=14)
cb = plt.colorbar()



cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)



plt.grid(b=None)
```

I'd like to reverse the order of the colors. Most answers I've found out deal with colormap but I'm just using colorbar.
How can i do it?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826754/change-the-labels-of-a-colorbar-from-increasing-to-decreasing-values)?

Comment: Not sure, I understand what you mean. But if you want to reverse the colors, check out my answer below and let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default colormap used when you call `matshow` is `viridis`. If you use the reverse `viridis` colormap (`viridis_r`) in your `matshow`, you will automatically get the reverse colorbar. See below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
c=np.random.choice(10,size=(10,10))

#Not reversed
ax1=plt.subplot(121)
ax1.set_title('Not reversed')
dat1=ax1.matshow(c)
cb1=plt.colorbar(dat1)

#reversed
ax2=plt.subplot(122)
ax2.set_title('Reversed')
dat2=ax2.matshow(c,cmap='viridis_r')
cb2=plt.colorbar(dat2)

plt.show()
```

See result below:

[image]